# Hector CassandraHostConfigurator - When to enable useThriftFramedTransport flag?

Tags: nosql, cassandra, hector

When one should enable useThriftFramedTransport setting? What is the benefit of using ThriftFramedTransport?

Answer (score 0):

You should always use framed transport - only framed transport is supported in Cassandra now.  The switch was made so that malformed requests couldn't cause the server to allocate too much memory and exit.